# Foreign language quiz and counting results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a program that quizzes the user on the translation of foreign words. Basically, the program provides a word and the user is to type in what the English word is for the Spanish one provided. Each time there is a right answer, the program gives an affirmative response; for each incorrect, give the correct answer. The program also needs to keep score and report at how many answers were correct at the end.

```
from random import shuffle

english_list = ["fire","apple","morning","river","wind","computer science",
                "biology","airplane","motorcycle","house","shower","wall",
                "eye","finger","head","goat","bird","dog","cat","office",
                "city"]

spanish_list = ["fuego","manzana","mañana","río","viento","informática",
                "biología","avión","motocicleta","casa","ducha","pared",
                "ojo","dedo","cabeza","cabra","ave","perro","gato","officina",
                "ciudad"]

def quizTime():
    english_to_spanish = dict(zip(english_list, spanish_list))
    spanish_to_english = dict(zip(spanish_list, english_list))

    print("Welcome to the English to Spanish Quiz! You will be tested"
          " on your knowledge of vocabulary words")

    print("Please type in the correct translation")

    for spanishWord, englishWord in spanish_to_english.items():
        response = input('What is the English word for ' + spanishWord + '? ')
        print(response == englishWord)
```

The code is supposed to quiz the user on the entire Spanish dictionary. I am confused on how to set up the code in a quiz format so the user can interact with it effectively. I am supposed to use the foreign words that are a part of pythons dictionary. How would one go about writing a similar code only using the Python dictionary to access these foreign words. Essentially, I cannot use the zip function like I have in this code.

Comment: use a `while` loop to keep prompting the user for an answer until they get it correct. You can also add an accumulator to keep track of the users tries and the score. That is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I will only try to fix the code you already have in the question, and since this is a homework I presume, you can expand on this

To begin with, you are not using the `random.shuffle` you imported
Also you don't need to create two zips, since you already know that all spanish-to-english translations are present at the same index for both, so you just need to iterate through both lists simultaneously, get the words at the same index, and see if the guess matches the english word.

```
english_list = ["fire","apple","morning","river","wind","computer science",
                "biology","airplane","motorcycle","house","shower","wall",
                "eye","finger","head","goat","bird","dog","cat","office",
                "city"]

spanish_list = ["fuego","manzana","mañana","río","viento","informática",
                "biología","avión","motocicleta","casa","ducha","pared",
                "ojo","dedo","cabeza","cabra","ave","perro","gato","officina",
                "ciudad"]

def quizTime():

    print("Welcome to the English to Spanish Quiz! You will be tested"
          " on your knowledge of vocabulary words")

    print("Please type in the correct translation")

    #Iterate through both lists
    for idx in range(len(spanish_list)):
        #Get the spanish and english word at same index
        spanishWord = spanish_list[idx]
        englishWord = english_list[idx]

        #Ask for user input and check if the translation matches
        response = input('What is the English word for ' + spanishWord + '? ')
        print(response == englishWord)

quizTime()
```

The output will be

```
Welcome to the English to Spanish Quiz! You will be tested on your knowledge of vocabulary words
Please type in the correct translation
What is the English word for fuego? fire
True
What is the English word for manzana? apple
True
What is the English word for mañana? morning
True
What is the English word for río? 
.....
```

UPDATE:

If your input is a dictionary, it would be a dictionary of spanish to english, and not english to spanish like in the comment, since we want to lookup the `value` english word against `key` spanish word, hence it would look like this:

```
vocabList = {'fuego': 'fire', 'manzana': 'apple', 'manana': 'morning', 'rio': 'river', 'viento': 'wind', 'informatica': 'computer science',
             'biologia': 'biology', 'avion': 'airplane', 'motocicleta': 'motorcycle', 'casa': 'house', 'ducha': 'shower', 'pared': 'wall',
             'ojo': 'eye', 'dedo': 'finger', 'cabenza': 'head', 'cabra': 'goat', 'ave': 'bird', 'perro': 'dog', 'gato': 'cat', 'officina': 'office', 'ciudad': 'city'}

def quizTime():

    print("Welcome to the English to Spanish Quiz! You will be tested"
          " on your knowledge of vocabulary words")

    print("Please type in the correct translation")

    #Iterate through key and value of dictionary
    for spanishWord, englishWord in vocabList.items():

        #Ask for user input and check if the translation matches
        response = input('What is the English word for ' + spanishWord + '? ')
        print(response == englishWord)

quizTime()
```

Comment: How could I edit this code if I changed both lists into a dictionary like this...vocabLsit = {"fire":"fuego","apple": "manzana","morning":"manana","river":"rio",
             "wind":"viento","computer science": "informatica",
             "biology": "biologia",
             "airplane": "avion","motorcycle":"motocicleta","house":"casa",
             "shower":"ducha","wall":"pared","eye":"ojo","finger":"dedo",
             "head":"cabenza","goat":"cabra", "bird":"ave","dog":"perro",
             "cat":"gato","office":"officina","city":"ciudad"}

Comment: Hi @goodvibes please consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped you :) by clicking the tick next to it :)